# The constructor being called is not a const

Tags: flutter, dart

I was just getting started with flutter and I am trying to create a small profile page I saw on YouTube. I built the page by stacking widgets under the children property of a Column widget. I have put the keyword 'const' before the children list. When I tried to add a Row Widget as one of the children I started to get this error:

```
The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.
```

```dart
class NetNinjaId extends StatelessWidget {
  const NetNinjaId({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'NetNinjaId',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [
              // Email
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 10.0),
                child: Row(children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.mail),
                  Text(
                    'abhinav03m@gmail.com',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        letterSpacing: 2.0),
                  ),
                ]),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Full code here: https://pastebin.com/8aCkHNjN
Error Screen shot:
[image]

Things I tried:

- Adding const keyword before the list inside the Row widget
- Adding const keyword to both widgets inside the children property of Row widget
- Removed the beginning const keyword, It worked but it gave more warnings suggesting to use const keyword.

Can anyone explain why this error is happening and what I can do to fix it. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: jsut try to closed your app and try to start again, if can't try to clean/adn pub get you prject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `const from`

```dart
    body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children:   [ //here
```

because `Row` doesn't use const constructor.

Comment: It works, but then vs code throws warning for rest of the widgets in the list since they use const constructor. Is there anyway i can surpress those warnings?

Comment: you can use linter on top but better add const rest of them as a good practice

Comment: Thanks, removing const and adding const to necessary widgets worked.